# join second table and select latest entry per timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a pattern matched search query that returns a maximum of 10 user given a keyword. It takes data from two tables: 'users' and 'uploads'.

'uploads' contains all the user uploads or no entry. I need the latest entry per timestamp or null for the column if none exists, for every found user that matches the keyword.

My problem is that I cant figure out a way to select *only* the latest upload entry for the user
(or *null* as the column value if no entry exists).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/767bb/3

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  "user_uuid" uuid NOT NULL,
  "username" varchar(25)
);

CREATE TABLE uploads (
  "file_uuid" uuid NOT NULL,
  "user_uuid" uuid NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamptz(6) DEFAULT now()
);

insert into uploads(file_uuid, user_uuid) values 
-- user1                                  
('aaa3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952', '0123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952'),
('bbb3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952', '0123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952'),
-- user2
('ccc3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952', '1123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952'),
('ddd3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952', '1123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952')
-- user 3 has no uploads
;


insert into users 
  (user_uuid, username) 
VALUES 
  ('0123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952', 'user1'),
  ('1123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952', 'user2'),
  ('2123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952', 'user3');
```

what i tried:

```
-- this query returns only one row
select
  us.username,
  us.user_uuid,
  up.file_uuid as cover,
  up.timestamp
 from users us
 right join (
   select file_uuid, user_uuid, timestamp
   from uploads
   order by timestamp
   limit 1
 ) up on us.user_uuid = up.user_uuid
 WHERE
    us.username ILIKE '%user%'
LIMIT 10;
```

what i expect

```
username    user_uuid   cover   timestamp

user1   0123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    aaa3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    2021-02-24T15:57:51.199186Z
user2   1123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    ddd3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    2021-02-24T15:57:51.199186Z
user3   2123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    null    2021-02-24T15:57:51.199186Z
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would clarify what you want to do.  It is quite unclear what the query in the fiddle has to do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (us.user_uuid) us.* ul.*
from users us left join
     uploads ul
     us.user_uuid = ul.user_uuid
where us.username ilike '%user%'
order by us.user_uuid, ul.timestamp desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 select
  us.username,
  us.user_uuid,
  up.file_uuid as cover,
  up.timestamp
 from users us
 left join uploads up on us.user_uuid = up.user_uuid
 left join (
    select user_uuid, max(timestamp) max_time
    from uploads
    group by user_uuid
 ) m ON m.user_uuid = up.user_uuid and max_time=up.timestamp
 WHERE
    us.username LIKE '%user%'
LIMIT 10;
```

With your data, it returns

```
user1   0123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    aaa3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    2021-02-24 16:34:35
user1   0123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    bbb3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    2021-02-24 16:34:35
user2   1123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    ccc3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    2021-02-24 16:34:35
user2   1123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    ddd3d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952    2021-02-24 16:34:35
user3   2123d0d1-a403-4af9-ba9e-c1df8fcb6952
```

Because every uploads have the same timestamp